# Any way/plugin to automatically change a members group based on an action?

Tags: members

I'm wondering if there is a way to change a users/registered members group based on them performing an action?

At the moment members register into a default group. If that member submits a specific entry via a channel form I would like to change their member group. Is there a way to automate this? Plugin or otherwise?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of anything available publicly at this time, but I think a custom extension could be built to accommodate using the following hook:

[Channel Form Hook {submit_entry_end}](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/extension_hooks/module/channel_form/index.html#channel-form-submit-entry-end) - triggered after a channel form is submitted

*Requires EE 2.7.0+*

Comment: Possibly so. Well beyond my capability though ! :)

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a plug-in to do this some time back for EE1.x, should be pretty easy to upgrade to EE2.x if you want to fork it...

https://github.com/ninefour/change_member_group.pi.ee_addon/blob/master/system/plugins/pi.change_member_group.php

Of course, use with caution!

:)